# DB2 ADD a new COLUMN to a table with DEFAULT value from an EXPRESSION using existing data in another column

Tags: sql, db2, ddl, alter-table

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN new_column_name data_type DEFAULT expression;
```

Is it possible to use an existing column data as default value for a new column in DB2?

```
ALTER TABLE employees ADD COLUMN work_hours INT DEFAULT (man_days);
```

Or an expression like this for the default value?

```
ALTER TABLE employees ADD COLUMN work_hours INT DEFAULT ( CASE WHEN salary < 50000 THEN (man_days + 10) * 24
   WHEN salary >= 50000 THEN (man_days) * 24 END);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With currently shipping versions of IBM Db2, regardless of the platform, you cannot use an `ALTER TABLE` statement to specify an expression-based default value.

There are minor differences between the Db2-platforms (LUW, Z/OS, i) for the syntax of the `default-clause`, but all limit the options to be based on null or special registers or constants.

You can achieve what you need by a combination of DDL and subsequent SQL statements.

[Db2-LUW alter table](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-alter-table)

[DB2-for-Z/OS alter table](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=statements-alter-table)

[Db2-for-i alter table](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=statements-alter-table)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. As you suggested I will create a DDL and a DML scripts to achieve this.